# Update Json File in a static Angularjs Website

Tags: json, angularjs, static, blogs

I'm trying to make a static blog in my website. I have a json file which contains the posts to be displayed.
Then I have a modal window where I will create a new post. 
I can see the result and the site shows the new post, but when the page is reloaded the new post is gone.
I'd like to update the json file without using a backend, only using angularjs, is it possible?

I tried this without success:

**Posts.html:**

```
     <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="post in posts">
       <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
        <p>June 17, 2014</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-5">
        <a ui-sref="/posts/{{ posts.indexOf(post) }}">
            <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="http://placehold.it/600x300" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>
            <a href="#/post/{{ posts.indexOf(post) }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </h3>
        <p>by <a href="#/post/{{ posts.indexOf(post) }}">{{ post.author }}</a>
        </p>
        <p>{{ post.exerpt }}</p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/post/{{ posts.indexOf(post) }}">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <hr>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="showModal()">Add New Post</button>
```

**Posts.js:**

```
    .controller('PostsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$modal', function($scope, $http, $modal){
  $http.get('data/posts.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.posts = data;
  });
    $scope.showModal=function () {
        $scope.newPost={};
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            url:'/addpost',
            templateUrl: 'views/addpost.html',
            controller:'AddpostCtrl',
            resolve: {
                newPost: function() {
                    return $scope.newPost;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
            $scope.posts.push({
                author: $scope.newPost.author,
                title: $scope.newPost.title,
                exerpt: $scope.newPost.exerpt,
                content: $scope.newPost.content
            });
        });
    };
}]);
```

**addpost.html:**

```
       <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="cancel()" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         <h1>New Post</h1>
       </div>

       <div class="modal-body">
         <label>Author</label><input type="text" ng-model="newPost.author"/>
         <label>Title</label><input type="text" ng-model="newPost.title"/>
         <label>Summary</label><textarea type="text" ng-model="newPost.exerpt"/>
         <label>Content</label><textarea type="text" ng-model="newPost.content"/>
         <br/>
         <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addNewPost()"> Add Post</button>
       </div>
```

**addpost.js:**

```
        .controller('AddpostCtrl',['$scope', '$modalInstance','newPost','$http', function ($scope, $modalInstance,newPost,$http) {
  $scope.newPost=newPost;
  $scope.addNewPost=function(newPost){

      $http.get('data/posts.json').success(function(data){
          $scope.posts = data;
          $scope.posts.push({newPost: newPost});
      });

    $modalInstance.close(newPost);
  };
  $scope.cancel =function(){
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
  }]);
```

I don't know if I could use angular local storage or any other solution.

Thanks a lot for the help!!!!

Comment: "I'd like to update the json file without using a backend, only using angularjs, is it possible?" Nope. A local storage solution would be an alternative solution to using a JSON file, but it'd only affect your current computer - no other visitors would see blog entries as they'd exist only in your computer's local storage.

Comment: Ok thanks @ceejayoz. Would you know how to achieve the static blog please?

Comment: You need either a non-static backend to generate that JSON (consider something like Jekyll, perhaps), or directly manipulate the JSON using a text editor. Static means static.

Comment: Thank you man! I´ll try  the non-static backend.